# load jquery-ui-bundle with laravel-mix (webpack)

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

In 5.2 I was using gulp and I just set this in app.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');require('jquery-ui-bundle');
```

This doesn't work anymore so I was able to load jquery from webpack.mix.js like this:

```
.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
});
```

But how do I load jquery-ui-bundle?

Comment: If you are on Laravel 5.4 or 5.5 jQuery is loaded in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`. This file should be required in `resources/assets/js/app.js`.

Comment: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put all your JS file and components in `resources/assets/js/`
and

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/.....js', 'public/js');
```

Compile and Run using npm

Comment: I am already mixing `js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')` in webpack and in app.js I have `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery-ui-bundle');` still it's not working with error: `mainsearch.js:3930 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).autocomplete is not a function TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function` (mainsearch.js is a script that uses autocomplete)